# How To Track the Cursor Position?

Tags: inputfield, button

I have 2 `InputFields` and 2 `Buttons`. I would like that when the user clicks the Pi `Button` or -Pi `Button`, that value will be assigned to that `InputField` only where the cursor was (either the first input field or the second).

```
Button["Range", (DialogInput[{range1 = 0, range2 = 0}, 
Column[{"Enter the Range", 
 Panel[Column[{InputField[Dynamic[range1], Number], 
    InputField[Dynamic[range2], Number], 
    Button["-Pi", (range2 = -3.14159;)], 
    Button["Pi", (range1 = 3.14159;)]}]]}]]), Method -> "Queued"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

For your usage, you could simply use a `PasteButton[]` instead.

```
Button["Range", (DialogInput[{range1 = 0, range2 = 0}, 
Column[{"Enter the Range", 
 Panel[Column[{InputField[Dynamic[range1], Number], 
    InputField[Dynamic[range2], Number], 
    PasteButton["-Pi", -3.14159, Appearance -> Automatic], 
    PasteButton["Pi", 3.14159, Appearance -> Automatic]}]]}]]), 
Method -> "Queued"]
```